# visualize 2-dimensional array visual basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, multidimensional-array, listbox

I started making a very simple application where a list of names is shown in a checked-listbox.
Now I would like to add a date as a second column value. This means i have two use a two-dimensional array.
What containers could be suitable to visualize a 2 dim-array on a form?

I was thinking as an alternative I could keep it one dimensional and use a delimiter. Would there then be a method to format this date on the extreme right side of a listbox? I guess I would have to extract the date part, but I don't see how i could position it in a listbox.

I am working with VS2010 and using a windows forms project. I have no experience in VB (but some in c++), and no experience with GUI's at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: ListView is going to be your easiest option. There are ways to get ListBox/CheckList bx to do it, but it's alot of code, and ListView does it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either the ListView in details/report mode or the DataGrid would be good. Personally I prefer the ListView when possible.